# How to initialize the fields of a class object through a class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

I'm having trouble initializing the fields of a class object member variable through a class constructor. 
This is part of the code that creates a Circle Object: 
[image]

And here's the class definition for the Circle and Point classes: 
[image]

[image]

Is this the appropriate way of writing the constructor for the Circle function? If so, what's the correct way of initializing the x and y fields for the center_ member variable? Would it be something like this:

```
 Circle::Circle(Point(int x, int y), double n)
 {
     radius_ = n;
     center_{x, y}; 
 }
```

Comment: What does your C++ textbook have to say on the subject?

Comment: No, it should be `Circle::Circle(Point p, double n)`. And please reread the class chapter in your C++ book.

Comment: This is such a basic question, it'll help you in the long run to work through the fundamentals of the language using a text book. Here's a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

A few error free constructors for the circle class would be the following:

```
Circle::Circle(Point x, double n);
Circle::Circle(int x, int y, double n); // Then create the point in the constructor
```